# Is it possible to attach a ref to a child received with this.props.children if children don't have ref attached to it?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

What is want is to create a reusable form handler that handle input validation on component passed to it as childs.

// this is my parent class rendering a form 
(Form) is where i want validation's to happen

```
  <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 16 }}>
    <Form>
      <MaterialInput placeholder="Email" value="Hamma" type="email" 
       />
      <MaterialInput placeholder="First name" type="text" />
      <MaterialInput placeholder="Last name" type="text" />
      <MaterialInput placeholder="Password" type="password" />
    </Form>
    {this.renderActionButton}
  </View>
```

// (Form) class looks like this. My problem is i want to assign a ref to child here in (Form) not in parent since parent won't be doing any thing with ref there so i want to avoid un-needed code in parent that will keep it clean and the reason i need ref on child is because with ref i can focus and set errors on childrens and access there values.

```
render() {
    const wrappedChildrens = [];

    React.Children.map(this.props.children, (Child, index) => {
      if (!Child) {
        return;
      }

      wrappedChildrens.push(
        React.cloneElement(Child, {
          key: `child.type_${index}`
        })
      );
    });

    return wrappedChildrens;
  }
```

Comment: you can simply set a ref key in React.cloneElement